# spark counting distinct values by key

Tags: apache-spark, key, distinct, pyspark

I am a newbie and know below commands. They give count of values by key and list of values by key.

```
dayToHostPairTuple.countByKey()
dayToHostPairTuple.groupByKey()
```

is there any simple alternative to countByKey that will count only distinct values by key?

#########################################==

Below code works for me. It is based upon answers that i received.

```
dayToHostPairTuple = access_logs.map(lambda log: (log.date_time.day, log.host))
dayToHostPairTuple=dayToHostPairTuple.sortByKey()
print dayToHostPairTuple.distinct().countByKey()
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but assuming I am correct you can solve it by mapping your k,v to (k,v), 1 and then reduceByKey on that, you will end up with [(k,v), count]

Comment: I tired your suggestion. My code is below `dayToHostPairTuple = access_logs.map(lambda log: (str(log.date_time.day)+"-"+str(log.host),1))`

`print dayToHostPairTuple.reduceByKey()` How should i change my second line?

Comment: You don't want to combine it as a string, you want to combine it as a python data structure. So something like dayToHostPairTuple.map(lambda k,v: (k,v),1 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that values are hashable you can use `distinct` with `countByKey`:

```
dayToHostPairTuple.distinct().countByKey()
```

or `reduceByKey`:

```
from operator import add

dayToHostPairTuple.distinct().keys().map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(add)
```

Comment: `dayToHostPairTuple.distinct().countByKey()` works. Is there a way to sort by key so that output is in ascending order of the key? I tried `dayToHostPairTuple.distinct().countByKey().sortByKey(true)` but i get an error :(

Comment: Without collecting you can use `sortByKey`. Locally (countByKey) it just a standard Python dict.You can extract items and sort. `true` is not valid Python boolean. And countByKey doesn't return RDD

Comment: I recommend using reduceByKey that is performed at the executors, over countByKey that is performed on the driver, especially for large datasets. To get the results add: final_counts = dict(dayToHostPairTuple.collect()).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest

dayToHostPairTuple.countApproxDistinctByKey(0.005)

From help:

> Return approximate number of distinct values for each key in this RDD.
>   The algorithm used is based on streamlib's implementation of
>   "HyperLogLog in Practice: Algorithmic Engineering of a State of The
>   Art Cardinality Estimation Algorithm", available here. 
>   relativeSD - Relative accuracy. Smaller values create counters that require more space. It must be greater than 0.000017